# How to model scalar values with a neural network if besides direction the magnitude matters too

Tags: neural-network, activation-function

Say you want to predict temperature changes based on some input data. Temperature changes are positive or negative scalars with a mean of zero. If only the direction matters one could just use tanh as an activation function in the output layer. But say for delta-temperatures predicting the magnitude of the change is also important, not just the sign.

How would you model this output. Tanh doesn't seem to be a good choice because it gives values between -1 and 1. And say temperature changes have a gaussian, or some other weird distribution, so hovering around the center quasi-linear domain of tanh(+-0) would be difficult to learn for a neural network. I'm worried that the sign would be good but the magnitude output would be useless.

How about having the network output one-hot vectors of length N, treat the argmax of this output vector as a temperature change on a pre-defined window. Say the window is -30 - +30 degrees, using N=60 long one-hot vector, if argmax( output )=45 that means the prediction is about 15 degrees.

I was actually not sure how to search for this topic.

Comment: You could use a linear output, which may perform well for the type of problem you're having. If a linear output is not performing well, you could also try a tanh output with a scaling factor, so the output is between -scalingFactor and +scalingFactor.

Comment: Why not treat it as a regression problem?